# Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, how would you find the derivative of the definite integral if the upper limit is just $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to find the derivative of the definite integral using the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$f(x)=\int_0^{g(x)}  t^2\sin(t^2) \, \mathrm{d}t $$

I know that you must substitute the upper limit to the $t$ variables in the integrand like this and multiply by the derivative of the upper limit.

$$f'(x) = (g(x))^2\sin((g(x))^2)* g'(x)$$

I was wondering whether this would be the final answer? There is no given expression for the function $g(x)$.

Comment: "I know that you must substitute the upper limit to the t variables in the integrand like this and multiply by the derivative of the upper limit". Ok, then why you opened this question?

Comment: If there is no given expression for $g(x)$, then you cannot obtain anything else than your result.